# Cannot install Groovy Eclipse plugin for Rational Application Developer v9.0 dependency conflict

Tags: eclipse, groovy, ibm-rad

I desire to install the GRECLIPSE plugin from spring in my installation of RAD v9.0 and am coming across a dependency conflict as shown below:

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Groovy-Eclipse Feature 2.8.0.xx-20130703-1600-e43-RELEASE (org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.feature.feature.group 2.8.0.xx-20130703-1600-e43-RELEASE)
  Software currently installed: IBM Software Delivery Platform_1 2014.1.23.172709 (IBM Software Delivery Platform_1 com.ibm.sdp.eclipse.ide 2014.1.23.172709)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Java Development Tools Core 3.8.3.xx-20130703-1700-e42-RELEASE (org.eclipse.jdt.core 3.8.3.xx-20130703-1700-e42-RELEASE)
    Java Development Tools Core 3.9.0.xx-20130703-1600-e43-RELEASE (org.eclipse.jdt.core 3.9.0.xx-20130703-1600-e43-RELEASE)
    Java Development Tools Core 3.8.4.v20130621-1225 (org.eclipse.jdt.core 3.8.4.v20130621-1225)
```

I was wondering if there was anyway of resolving these dependency issues without corrupting rad or whether I have no option but to give up hope on being able to edit groovy from within rad.

**EDIT:** in response to the comment, i am using the 4.2 update site when this error occurs.

Comment: From the look of it the RAD you have is based on Eclipse 4.2 (e42 release) and Groovy wants Eclipse 4.3 (e43). If you can find a Groovy release for 4.2 it may work.

Comment: I am using the 4.2 update site already unfortunately.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue trying to get groovy ide to work in RAD eclipse (v 9.1), anyone ever solve this? Seems really silly to install a different ide just to work with groovy